# NodeJs how to use MomentJs?

Tags: node.js, momentjs

I am trying to get current date time in the following format -

```
2018-12-10T02:12:13.008391
```

I opted to use MomentJs, as many devs are suggesting it but
I'm unable to get a current date time the above format.

I tried the following code but I am unable to understand what the last part of the date time is after the **.(dot)**
The given datetime has 6 values after the .(dot),
But I am able to get only 4 values after the .(dot).

```
2019-03-19T10:18:20.1820
```

Can someone please help me with the correct Format and way to achieve my use case?

```
var moment = require('moment');
var datetime = moment().format('YYYY-MM-DDThh:mm:ss.ms');
console.log(datetime);
```

I tried referring the following link, but wasn't able to as I'm new to JS - 
https://devhints.io/moment

Comment: Just so it's clear, why do you need exactly that format?. Seems basically ISO format. Which you can get it from: `moment().toISOString()` or `moment().toISOString(true)`

Comment: Payment related application I believe.

Comment: I'm pretty sure sending a valid ISO date will do it.

Comment: moment().toISOString() -> 2019-03-19T14:29:30.996Z, moment().toISOString(true) -> 2019-03-19T22:29:30.996+08:00

Comment: Yes, I know. It's probably all you need. Because the other format doesn't make much sense, and that ISO date generated by moment can be parsed by any language/date library.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`const dateTime = moment().format('YYYY-MM-DDTHH:mm:ss.SSS000');`

Moment will not be able to get you 6 decimal places for the time, because it's based on the built-in JavaScript Date object, which can only get you down to milliseconds. Your best bet would be to pad the time with zeroes if you really have to have 6 decimal places.